# Uploading a csv file to snowflake using fivetran

Tags: fivetran

I want to upload csv files from google sheets to snowflake database. I would like to know if there is any option in fivetran such that only upserts(only modified rows) of these csv files are synced to snowflake table?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use Fivetran to upload Google Sheets data into Snowflake: https://fivetran.com/docs/files/google-sheets Fivetran by default only updates modified rows (adds/deletes/updates), so it will indeed upsert if that Google Sheet is modified. I believe by default Fivetran will only 'soft-delete' deletions from source data, so I think if you delete a row from your Google Sheet it will remain in Snowflake, but will have a _fivetran_deleted column flag. I would test this explicitly if this matters to you.

I'm not sure what you mean by 'only upserts'. No deletions of data once it's stored in Snowflake from Google Sheets? If so, Fivetran may already do exactly what you want out of the box. Fivetran will definitely insert new rows and update existing ones.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do this with Fivetran, but you can two-way sync a Google Sheet with Snowflake using [Wax](https://www.wax.run/) in real time (e.g. as soon as the Sheet is edited, the update is sent to Snowflake).

Disclaimer: I made this.

Comment: Fivetran can upsert Google Sheets data to sync it in Snowflake: https://fivetran.com/docs/files/google-sheets